# Hyper server drops connection on returning Async::NotReady in Future

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper

I'm trying to run a hyper server with an asynchronous response on a request using a future. When the future's `poll` method is called and returns `Async::NotReady`, the connection is just dropped ("dropping I/O source: 0"). I expected that the `poll` method is called multiple times until it returns `Async::Ready`.

The [example shown](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/examples/send_file.rs) returns an async io future which is doing (I guess) the same thing.

Why is the future's `poll` function just called once and why does hyper drop the connection after the future returns `Async::NotReady`?

Example Code: (hyper version is: v0.12.21)

```
use futures::{Async, Future, Poll};
use hyper::http::{Request, Response};
use hyper::service::service_fn;
use hyper::{Body, Server};

fn main() {
    let addr = ([127, 0, 0, 1], 3335).into();
    println!("Start request handler. (Listening on http://{})", addr);

    hyper::rt::run(
        Server::bind(&addr)
            .serve(|| service_fn(|request: Request<Body>| handle_request(request.uri().path())))
            .map_err(|e| println!("server error: {}", e)),
    );
}

type BoxedResponseFuture = Box<Future<Item = Response<Body>, Error = tokio::io::Error> + Send>;

fn handle_request(path: &str) -> BoxedResponseFuture {
    println!("Handle request {:?}", path);
    Box::new(
        ResponseFuture { ready: false }
            .and_then(|_| {
                let response = Response::new(Body::from("Success".to_string()));

                Ok(response)
            })
            .or_else(|e| {
                let response = Response::new(Body::from(format!("Error: {:?}", e)));

                Ok(response)
            }),
    )
}

struct ResponseFuture {
    ready: bool,
}

impl Future for ResponseFuture {
    type Item = ();
    type Error = ();

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Self::Item, Self::Error> {
        println!("Poll future");

        if self.ready {
            println!("Future ready");

            return Ok(Async::Ready(()));
        }

        println!("Future not ready");
        self.ready = true;
        Ok(Async::NotReady)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper is built on top of the futures crate and uses its future model known as a "readiness" or "pull" where values are pulled out of futures on demand, and otherwise a task is **notified** when a value might be ready to get pulled out.

When `poll` returns `NotReady`, the current task **must** register for a readiness change notification, otherwise the task may never be completed. Any function that returns `Async` must adhere to it.

In other words, you should wait until `poll` can return `Ready` or notify the current task to indicate that it is ready to make progress and return `NotReady`

```
// notify about progress
fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Self::Item, Self::Error> {
    println!("Poll future");

    if self.ready {
        println!("Future ready");

        return Ok(Async::Ready(()));
    }

    println!("Future not ready");
    self.ready = true;

    // The executor will poll this task next iteration
    futures::task::current().notify();
    Ok(Async::NotReady)
}

// wait until it is Ready
fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Self::Item, Self::Error> {
    loop {
        println!("Poll future");

        if self.ready {
            println!("Future ready");
            return Ok(Async::Ready(()));
        }

        println!("Future not ready");
        self.ready = true;
    }
}
```

Tokio's docs [1](https://tokio.rs/docs/going-deeper/tasks/) [2](https://tokio.rs/docs/internals/runtime-model/) might clarify it.

Comment: Thank you for the short explanation. I should dig deeper into Tokio's documentation I guess.